# JS: variable inheritance in anonymous functions - scope

Tags: javascript, scope, anonymous-function

Long story short:

```
var o="before";
x = function() //this needs to be an anonymous function
{
  alert(o); //the variable "o" is from the parent scope
};
o="after"; //this chages "o" in the anonymous function

x();
//this results in in alert("after");
//which is not the way i want/need it
```

in reality my code is somewhat more complex.

My script iterates through many html objects and adds an event listener each element.

I do this by declaring an anonymous function for each element and call another function with an ID as argument. that ID is represented by the "o"-variable in this example.

After some thinking I understand why it is the way it is, but is there a way to get js to evaluate o as i declare the anonymous function without dealing with the id attribute and fetching my ID from there?

My full source code is here: http://pastebin.com/GMieerdw

The anonymous function is on line 303.

Comment: Definitely the most-asked Javascript question here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using a self-invoking function like this:

```
var o = 0;
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    (function(obj,variable){
        obj.onclick = function(){
            alert(variable);
        }
    })(elements[i],o);
    o++;
}
```

That should alert "o" at whatever value it was during the loop, instead of alerting the final value of "o".

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: soo... i tried the other approach first because this one looks a bit difficult. but... IT WORKS!! thank you very much. i nearly lost all hope

Comment: im glad i could help in some way. both methods are very similar.

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a closure of your variable `o`. You can do this by assigning a function that accepts a value returns a function which uses that value. Your example can be modified like this to get the desired effect:

```
var o="before";
x = function(inner) {
    return function()
    {
      alert(inner);
    }
} (o); //here, the anonymous function is called, which will return another function which uses o
o="after";

x();//prints "before"
```

For a more detailed description, see [the MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures), which has a section about using closures with loops.

This same technique can be applied in your loop. Something like this is what you would want to do:

```
var fn = function(x, y) {
    return function() {
        rr_download_start(x, y);
    }
} (i, this);
link.addEventListener('click', fn ,false);
```

Comment: It can become a little confusing if you do, but you can make `x=function(o){return function() { alert(o); }}(o);` too, that way the name of the variable doesn't change...

Comment: yes, it's quite similar to tau's solution: an anonymous function in an anonymous function. i didn't try this one but i'm sure it also works! his solution is just a bit more what i need.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function:

```
function curry(fun, arg) {
  return function() {
    return fun(arg);
  };
};

// start loop 
var o="before";
x = curry(function(o) {
  alert(o);
}, o);
o="after";

x(); // "before"
```

Another way is to use an external data source - since `this` will depend on where the function was called, you can store the value in the DOM node to which you bind the handler. This way you can use a single function instead lots of anonymous functions. This technique has a few caveats (circular references can cause memory leaks in IE6), but frameworks can have a nice clean wrapper for it. E. g. in jQuery you can write:

```
function doStuff() {
  alert($(this).data('o'));
}

// start loop
var o="before";
someDomElement.data('o', 'before');
someDomElement.bind('someEvent', doStuff);
o="after";

someDomElement.trigger('someEvent'); // "before"
```